# Start and stopping external program?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to start and stop an external program in Python3, on Linux.
This program is an executable, called `smip-tun,`  located in the same folder as the source code and I'd like to be able to execute and control it from there with relative names.

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
smip_tun = 0

def start_smip_tun(self):
    smip_tun =  subprocess.Popen(['smip-tun',DEFAULT_SERIAL_PORT])

def end_smip_tun(self):
    smip_tun.terminate()
    print("end")
```

But says it cannot find `smip-tun`. Efforts to specify the relative directory have failed. I was trying with `cwd` but cannot figure it out.
Any advice?

Edit:

Made Smip-tun global but the issue persists.

New code:

```
smip_tun = 0

def start_smip_tun(self):
    global smip_tun
    smip_tun =  subprocess.Popen(['smip-tun',DEFAULT_SERIAL_PORT])

def end_smip_tun(self):
    global smip_tun
    smip_tun.terminate()
    print("end")
```

Error message:

```
  File "/home/sven/git/cerberos_manager/iot_network_api.py", line 40, in start_smip_tun
    smip_tun = subprocess.Popen(['smip-tun',DEFAULT_SERIAL_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'smip-tun'
```

Comment: You need to declare `smip_tun` global, see [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/423379/45249)

Comment: @mouviciel This is a perfectly fine answer ;)

Comment: More specifically, add a `global smip_tun` statement to the beginning of the `start_smip_tun()` function.

Comment: I've incoporated your advice, but the issue persists.

Comment: You had two issues. The `global` advice solved the one you didn't see because of the second one. Now, you have to specify the path of `smip-tun` or include that path in your `PATH` environment variable (e.g., `export PATH=.:$PATH`).

Comment: Yes indeed, but my main question was on how to do that relative to the directory the script itself is executing in. Smip-tun is located in the same directory as the .py file.

Comment: I am a bit slow. The mistake is that I need to specify "./smip-tun" to execute, not smip-tun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

os.chdir('.') # or change the . for the full path directory.

smip_tun =  subprocess.Popen(['smip_tun',DEFAULT_SERIAL_PORT])
```

Also make sure your app do not have any extension, like `smip-tun.py` and `smip-tun.sh`